# How to send SMS notifications to other signed up mobile numbers in a social networking firebase app

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-authentication, sms

I am developing an Android app with only phone number as a signup, whenever the users do any sort of an activity how should send SMS notifications using Firebase.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Imported firebase fcm packages and dependencies , tried my hand at setting up a Node.js Script to receive notifications, But the method wasnt of any help . Because  i WANT to set up notifications for every user activity

Answer (score 3):

Firebase doesn't have a product that supports sending SMS notifications to users. The only SMS connection is through Firebase Authentication's phone-number sign-in, but you can't change the message that is sent there.

If you're looking to send notifications through Firebase Cloud Messaging, you can see how to set that up here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client